# Why is my required Strong parameter not picked up?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not able to find the reason for why my strong parameters are not getting saved in the database. I'm not using scaffolding to create my models rather using the `rails g model Customer Name:string Email:string` command. The same gets added when using `rails console`.

This is my pages controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController 

def Home

end

def Login

@customer=Customer.new(master)
@customer.save

end
 private
 def attr @customer=Customer.find(params[:id]) end 
def master params.require(:customer).permit(:Name,:Email) end end
```

My customer.rb file

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :Products,through: :Order

end
```

The development logs while trying to save a new Customer.

```
Started GET "/Login?Customer%5BName%5D=s&Customer%5BEmail%5D=csc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-31 04:48:49 +0530 Processing by PagesController#Login as HTML Parameters: 

{"Customer"=>{"Name"=>"s", "Email"=>"csc"}} (0.1ms) begin transaction SQL (0.5ms)

 INSERT INTO "customers" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?) [["created_at", Wed, 30 Oct 2013 23:18:49 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 30 Oct 2013 23:18:49 UTC +00:00]] (72.4ms) commit transaction Rendered pages/Login.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms) Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 5.7ms | ActiveRecord: 73.0ms)
```

The error I am getting while opening the page in browser:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PagesController#Login
param not found: customer
Extracted source (around line #17):
```

Comment: Your fields should be lower-case, `name` and `email`, *not* `Name` and `Email`. This stuff matters, Rails contentions are important.

Comment: Hi tried everything but it throws an error of param :customer not found.Am I doing something wrong here other than the case sensitive error because i tried making a new test rails app with everything in lowercase but still doesn't work.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case matters. Your passing in `Customer`, but requiring `customer`. These are *different* parameters. Switch everything to **lower case**, except the actual classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your `params.require` you specify `customer`, in your params you have `Customer`. This makes a difference. As a rule of thumb: always use lowercase.

Comment: I tried your advise .Made a new rails app with everything with lowercase. Still the error persits that parameter :customer not found.